# python count business weeks

Tags: python, datetime

Given a start date, how can I determine how many "business weeks" it's been with Python?  I can't just divide by 7 because that won't give me the correct answer.

An example would be a start date of Aug 1 2012 to the current date (Aug 13 2012) would output 3 weeks.

I'm basically trying to figure out from the start of the football season, what the current week (integer) is.

I've tried messing around with Pythons datetime module, but it's been to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [datetime.weekday](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday), [datetime.isoweekday](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoweekday) to get the current day of the week or use the more complete [datetime.isocalendar](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isocalendar) to also get the current week of the year and using those as offsets to calculate an aligned difference.

So you can have a function like this:

```
def week_difference(start, end):
    assert start <= end
    start_year, start_week, start_dayofweek = start.isocalendar()
    end_year, end_week, end_dayofweek = end.isocalendar()

    return ((end_year - start_year) * 52) - start_week + end_week
```

With usage like this:

```
import datetime as dt
# same week
In [1]: week_difference(dt.datetime(2012, 8, 1),  dt.datetime(2012, 8, 1))
Out[1]: 0

# your example (see note below) 
In [2]: week_difference(dt.datetime(2012, 8, 1),  dt.datetime(2012, 8, 13))
Out[2]: 2

# across years
In [3]: week_difference(dt.datetime(2011, 8, 1),  dt.datetime(2012, 8, 13))
Out[3]: 54

# year boundary: second last business week of 2011, to first business week of 2012
# which is the same business week as the last business week of 2011
In [4]: week_difference(dt.datetime(2011, 12, 20),  dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1))
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: week_difference(dt.datetime(2011, 12, 18),  dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1))
Out[5]: 2
```

You can add `1` to your week output depending on your chosen semantic of what a week difference should be.

Comment: You can get rid of the if/else at the end. Just return the first statement - it works when the years are the same

Comment: @jterrace ah of course. The year part zeros out if same year. I built up the function piecemeal and somehow did not notice this. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you get your datetime object...

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
start = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 5)
```

...you can additionally use [isocalendar](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar)...

```
today.isocalendar()
>>> (2012, 33, 1)
start.isocalendar()
>>> (2012, 36, 3)
```

This 3-tuple returns the year, week of the year, and the day of the week. If you just care about a single year, then you can simply subtract the "week of the year" values (I might be off by one here..). Otherwise, you'll need to get the year involved.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
datetime.date.isocalendar(datetime.date.today())[1] - datetime.date(2012, 8, 1).isocalendar()[1] + 1
```

Comment: Not bad, seems to work well.  Anyway it can be modified to return negative numbers if it's before the start date?

Comment: @ Preet Kukreti  what do you mean by year boundaries?

Comment: @bababa see the usage in my answer. I mean that if you just compare the weeks then it will not work when the dates are in different years. One example is December to Jan comparison.

Comment: @ bababa and Preet Kukreti:
Yes, this works only within a calendar year (e.g. 15/08/2011 till today will return 3 weeks as well and not 55 as it should), but because you're talking about a football season I didn't include the counting of the years (and assumed that the season will be played within one calendar year)

Comment: @ bababa and Preet Kukreti: Please see my new comment/code which considers year boundaries

Answer (score 0):

My one-liner extended to include year boundaries:

```
start_date = datetime.date(2012, 8, 1)
print ((datetime.date.isocalendar(datetime.date.today())[0]-datetime.date.isocalendar(start_date)[0])*52)+(datetime.date.isocalendar(datetime.date.today())[1]-datetime.date.isocalendar(start_date)[1])+1
>>> 3
```

Note: This function will still return negative values if start_date is in the future (from today)!